# Not able to apply AggregateByKey using Spark Scala to get (id, total,( max, min)) for given input(id, value)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I have tried this code but it says Tuples cannot be destructured.

```
forditems.map(stre=>(stre.split(",")(1).toInt, stre.split(",")(4).toFloat)).aggregateByKey((0.0f, (0.0f, 0.0f)))(
(t,v) => (t._1 + v, ( if(v > t._2._1) v else  t._2._1 , if(v > t._2._2) v else  t._2._2 ))
(x,t) => (x._1 + t._1, (if(x._2._1 < t._2._1) t._2._1 else  x._2._1, if(x._2_.2 < t._2._2) t._2._2 else  x._2._2 )))
```

error message

```
<console>:7: error: not a legal formal parameter.
Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
  Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,
  or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1) => ... }
 (x,t) => (x._1 + t._1, (if(x._2._1 < t._2._1) t._2._1 else  x._2._1, 
 if(x._2_.2 < t._2._2) t._2._2 else  x._2._2 ))).filter(stre=> 
 stre._1==2).take(10).foreach(println)
 ^
 <console>:7: error: ')' expected but double literal found.
 (x,t) => (x._1 + t._1, (if(x._2._1 < t._2._1) t._2._1 else  x._2._1, 
 if(x._2_.2 < t._2._2) t._2._2 else  x._2._2 ))).filter(stre=> 
 stre._1==2).take(10).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually just tiny syntactic mistakes here:

- Comma missing between the first and second arguments passed to `aggregateByKey` (end of second line)
- You typed `x._2_.2` instead of `x._2._2`

Fixing these would give the output you want.

**BUT** - That said, it's worth noting that Scala offers much nicer syntactic options for dealing with tuples and performing simple arithmetic operations. More importantly, tuples shouldn't be over-used, and a common alternative is to create a **case class** that better supports the operations you're trying to perform.

For example - we can create a simple `Stats` case class that has an `agg` method:

```
case class Stats(total: Float, min: Float, max: Float) {
  def agg(other: Stats): Stats = Stats(
    total + other.total,
    math.min(min, other.min),
    math.max(max, other.max)
  )
}
```

And then use `reduceByKey` with this function:

```
val result: RDD[(Int, Stats)] = forditems
  .map(_.split(",")).map(arr => (arr(1).toInt, arr(4).toFloat))
  .mapValues(f => Stats(f, f, f))
  .reduceByKey(_ agg _)
```

Moreover, if you're willing to use Spark's **DateFrames** - this becomes even simpler:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = forditems.map(_.split(",")).map(arr => (arr(1).toInt, arr(4).toFloat)).toDF("k", "v")

val resultDf = df.groupBy("k").agg(sum($"v"), min($"v"), max($"v"))
resultDf.show()

// +---+------+------+------+
// |  k|sum(v)|min(v)|max(v)|
// +---+------+------+------+
// |  1| 444.0|   4.0| 400.0|
// +---+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code and provide more details and other alternatives @Tzach Zohar